How can I avoid false positives from user supplied text?
What should we be doing to handle false positives? Our users like to submit form text data which is occasionally denied by our Cloud Armor WAF.
Here is an example value submitted in the POST payload:

Please supply the following data: foo, bar and baz.

Rule owasp-crs-v030301-id941170-xss (NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: Attribute Injection) catches the data: , usage as a potential threat.
Is there a path we should be taking to reduce false positives when this happens?
What I've tried:

I'm aware that would could deactivate the rule which is less than ideal. I do not want to strip security down for every false positive.
In the immediate term we've told users to avoid using the word "data" followed by a colon.
url encoding does not work: data:dfgdf, converted to data%3A%20dfgdf%2C is picked up by WAF
escaping as data/:dfgds, passes the WAF but we'll need some transform before and after the WAF.
using HTML entities data&colon;dfgdf, also passes the WAF

Looks like escaping user supplied text is potential solution.
What I have not yet tried, is using sensitivity (paranoia) levels. Is this the preferred approach when dealing with false positives, or would you advise we escape user submitted data?
Can the sensitivity functionality be explained? It is range from 0-4 but regex pattern matches are boolean. What can we expect if sensitivity is set to 1 and a rule is a match?
Additionally to understand sensitivity. What is the sensitivity level equivalent to evaluatePreconfiguredExpr?

Check this blog by DevCodeF1, it may help to resolve your issue.

The sensitivity levels just leverage a larger or smaller set of OWASP signatures. The sensitivity levels range from 1 (fewest signatures) to 4 (largest number of signatures), although not all OWASP rules have 4 levels of signature profiles.
If the escaping of rules doesn't work for you, perhaps consider excluding fields from the request as a way to not have to remove entire signatures. Usingally upping the sensitivity level just creates even more noise and rules tuning headaches, but it is very workload specific so I wouldn't go as far as saying if you raise your sensitivity level, it will always cause more issues. One thing to keep in mind is that Cloud Armor will find the first rule match and stop. So, you may encounter during your rules tuning that there are several signatures within a particular OWASP rule that gets tripped, but you will only discover this as you are iteratively going through the rules tuning process.
I'd also recommend enabling verbose logging while you are doing rules tuning. This can help zero in what specifically is causing Cloud Armor to complain.
